# OnPaint TextBox Issue -

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been having an issue when using the OnPaint event on a TextBox.
Whenever I click on the text area with the mouse or when I start to type, the background of the text box changes back to white. Any idea what can cause that?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    protected override void OnCreateControl() {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer
            | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer 
            | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
            | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw
            | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
        SolidBrush bBrush = new SolidBrush(Enabled ? BackColor : Color.LightGray);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bBrush, ClientRectangle);
        bBrush.Dispose();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Brush aBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) {
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            switch (TextAlign) {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                    break;
            }
            string text = UseSystemPasswordChar && !Enabled
                ? new StringBuilder(Text.Length).Insert(0, PasswordChar.ToString(), Text.Length).ToString()
                : Text;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, (Font)Font.Clone(), aBrush, ClientRectangle, sf);
            aBrush.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `TextBox` doesn't support painting well. It's a pretty old control. What's your requirement?

Comment: _I have been having an issue when using the OnPaint event on a TextBox_ Don't!

Comment: `using (Brush aBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))`: so the foreground is the same (no *multicolor text*). It appears you're doind this just to change the background color. You can do that using the standard `BackColor` property. You can also use a RichTextBox.

Comment: Jimi, i can't because the BackColor is different for the focused field (yellow) all other fields have a white background. When I move the cursor outside of the textbox it looks good. It's only when I click within the box or when I start typing that the background color changes. The funny thing is that is only changes for the area where there is text - as you can see from the screenshot attached. I wonder if there is some kind of different windows message "WM_???" I should handle...

Comment: You can use the `Enter` and `Leave` events to change the BackColor of a TextBox..

Comment: That's what I'm doing (focus gained/lost) but when used with onPaint(), there is this problem I was talking about. The reason why I'm using onPaint() is because I want to override the display when the TextBox is disabled - which works fine. It's only when the textbox is enabled & has the focus by clicking or typing that the problem occurs.